# Run time error 91: object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

Please can someone help me: I am getting error 91 but don't know how to fix my code. I am quite new to VBA

```
Sub createQuote()

'Declare variables
Dim wd As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim iRow As Long 'Variable to hold starting row
Dim wsheet As Worksheet 'Variable for which worksheet to refer to

'Start word and new document
Set wd = New Word.Application

'Set worksheet where table is available
Set wsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Merge Items")

iRow = 2 'Data is starting at row 2

'Opening the word template
Set wDoc = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Prowess Documents\Prowess Electrical Solutions Ltd\Automation Test Documents\Quote Document Template_Bookmarks.docx")

wd.Visible = False

'Code to insert values from specific bookmark in word application

'Quote Number
wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="QuoteNumber"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=wsheet.Range("A" & iRow).Value
```

It stops at `wd.Selectioin.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Quote Number"`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: is it supposed to be `QuoteNumber` or `Quote Number`? (those are not the same thing)

Comment: Strange, because that would mean that the Application.Selection object is nothing. Have you tried making word visible before opening the document?

Comment: Hi braX - it is supposed to be QuoteNumber

Comment: Hi Steeeve, yes I have tried making word visible but I seem to still be getting the error. Thank you Holly

Comment: This is also problematic: `ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\"` because it would have 2 paths then, so that line would never work.

Comment: Hi braX - I will have a look at sorting that in the morning. Still learning so appreciate the feedback. Thank you Holly

Comment: @braX: ACK and it would also explain the error, but without an `on error resume next` the code should already throw an error on that line. Holly, have you removed some relevant codelines? ;) Or does Documents.Open fail silently with invalid filenames?

Comment: Do you have a bookmark called `QuoteNumber`? Or are you expecting it to work like a `Find`? At any rate, much more information is needed in order to help.

Comment: Also, if it's a template you are using, you should be using `wd.Documents.Add` instead of `wd.Documents.Open`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it worked for me, you need to have a bookmark that sepaplicated in selected text, it will be changed. It's not just the beginning of the word bookmark, it has to have at least one character selected in this bookmark, good luck.

```
Option Explicit
Private Function CreateQuote()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Dim wsheet As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Byte
    
    'Alternatively, we can use Late Binding (comments the first and second lines)
    'Dim wdApp As Object
    'Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    
Set wsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Merge Items")
iRow = 2
    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Open "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Prowess Documents\Prowess Electrical Solutions Ltd\Automation Test Documents\Quote Document Template_Bookmarks.docx"
        With .Selection
            .Goto what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="QuoteNumber"
            .TypeText wsheet.Range("A" & iRow).Value
        End With
    End With
   wdApp.Quit True 'Close and Save
End Function
```

Comment: If your answer gets an error, then why did you post it as an answer?

Comment: Why! Why! I asked myself the same question! and you see, one mistake does not justify the other! but yes, u in this one is correct because it was treatable error. I was correcting, I left the post there!!! oh oh

Answer (score 0):

### Append Excel Cell Value to Word Bookmark

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateQuote()
    
    Const wdFilePath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Prowess Documents\Prowess Electrical Solutions Ltd\Automation Test Documents\Quote Document Template_Bookmarks.docx"
    
    If Len(Dir(wdFilePath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file '" & wdFilePath & "' doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical, "CreateQuote"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Declare variables
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim iRow As Long 'Variable to hold starting row
    Dim wsheet As Worksheet 'Variable for which worksheet to refer to
    
    'Set worksheet where table is available
    Set wsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Merge Items")
    
    iRow = 2 'Data is starting at row 2
    
    'Start Word.
    Set wd = New Word.Application
    'wd.Visible = True ' the default value is 'False'
    
    On Error GoTo AppError ' close word if something goes wrong
    
    'Opening the word template
    Set wDoc = wd.Documents.Open(wdFilePath)
    
    'Code to insert values from specific bookmark in word application
    
    'Quote Number
    wd.Selection.Goto what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="QuoteNumber"
    wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=wsheet.Range("A" & iRow).Value

    'Some more code?

    ' You have to decide what to do here:

    'Save and close document.
    'wDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'If it's a template, you rather want to save as another file:
    'wdoc.saveas2(...)
    
SafeExit:
    
    'Close Word.
    wd.Quit
    
    Exit Sub

AppError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```